Override trace properties for legend display
How can I force the legend of a plotly 5.9 plot to use different parameters than were defined with the trace?
I have a scatter plot with overlaying low-opacity datapoints, and I want the legend to show the colors in full opacity. Also, I want to increase the marker size in the legend. I have no idea how to access these properties.
Here's the way I create my plots:
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import plot
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from IPython.display import display, HTML

x = np.random.rand(2000)
y1 = np.random.rand(2000)
y2 = np.random.randn(2000)

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)
 

trc1 = go.Scatter(x=x, y=y1, mode='markers', marker=dict(
    color='blue', size=2, opacity=0.2)
)
trc2 = go.Scatter(x=x, y=y2, mode='markers', marker=dict(
    color='green', size=4, opacity=0.2)
)

fig.add_trace(trc1, row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(trc2, row=1, col=2)

# This raises ValueError: Invalid property 'marker'
#fig.update_layout(legend=dict(marker=dict(opacity=1)))

# This works, but also updates the plots
#fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(marker=dict(opacity=1)))

display(HTML(plot(fig, output_type="div")))

Edit: Just for the marker size, the solution would be
fig.update_layout(legend={'itemsizing': 'constant'})

But how to adjust the opacity (or any other property of the marker)?

There is no way to do this directly using Plotly API, but you can pass a post_script (a javascript snippet that will override the styles of the involved HTML elements) to plotly.io.to_html().
For syntax highlighting, here is the JS code alone :
const gd = document.querySelector('.plotly-graph-div');

// Override opacity of legend layers (fill, lines, marker symbols)
const setLegendOpacity = () => {
  gd.querySelectorAll('.legend .layers path').forEach(el => {
    el.style.opacity = 1; // marker symbols
    el.strokeOpacity = 1; // fill, lines
  });
}

// Apply once 
setLegendOpacity();

// Reapply when needed (@see https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-events/)
gd.on('plotly_relayout', setLegendOpacity);
gd.on('plotly_restyle', setLegendOpacity);

Now in python :
js = '''
const gd = document.querySelector('.plotly-graph-div');
const setLegendOpacity = () => {
  gd.querySelectorAll('.legend .layers path').forEach(el => {
    el.style.opacity = 1; // marker symbols
    el.strokeOpacity = 1; // fill, lines
  });
}
setLegendOpacity();
gd.on('plotly_relayout', setLegendOpacity);
gd.on('plotly_restyle', setLegendOpacity);
'''

# display(HTML(plot(fig, output_type="div")))
 
display(HTML(plotly.io.to_html(
    fig,
    post_script=[js],
    full_html=False,       # output_type="div"
    include_plotlyjs=True  # offline 
)


The most unpythonic solution imaginable ;) But it works. Thanks a lot!

To date (20230513), it is the only solution indeed.
